# Problem with PyVISA & PyMeasure - how to solve it?

Tags: python, warnings

I am using Python 3.8. Installed PyMeasure using pip and entered the following single line to my file and executed it:

```
from pymeasure.instruments.keithley import Keithley2400
```

And I got the following output from Python:

```
*Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\visa.py", line 13
    warnings.warn(
FutureWarning: The visa module provided by PyVISA is being deprecated. You can replace `import visa` by `import pyvisa as visa` to achieve the same effect.
The reason for the deprecation is the possible conflict with the visa package provided by the https://github.com/visa-sdk/visa-python which can result in hard to debug situations.*
```

What is the problem here and how can I work around it to be able to code?

Comment: It is not an error, its a warning that `PyVISA` will be deprecated. It also says to use `import pyvisa as visa`, have you tried that?

Comment: @BernardL Yes, I did that but it did not affect the message.